# In C#, if I have generic objects, how can I generically specify getting and setting fields on those objects?

Tags: c#, object, generics, get, set

I have two very similiar functions:

```
        public Dictionary<string, T> UpdateSuccessProperties<T, TU>(Dictionary<string, T> oldSObjectByAlternativeIds, List<TU> updatedSObjects)
        where TU : T
        where T : AlternativeIdentifiable {
            updatedSObjects.ForEach((updatedSObject) => {
                    if (oldSObjectByAlternativeIds.TryGetValue(updatedSObject.GetAlternativeId(), out T oldSObject)) {
                        oldSObject.SalesforceId = updatedSObject.SalesforceId;
                    }
                });

            return oldSObjectByAlternativeIds;
        }
```

```
        public Dictionary<string, T> UpdateFailureProperties<T, TU>(Dictionary<string, T> oldSObjectByAlternativeIds, List<TU> updatedSObjects)
        where TU : T
        where T : AlternativeIdentifiable {
            updatedSObjects.ForEach((updatedSObject) => {
                    if (oldSObjectByAlternativeIds.TryGetValue(updatedSObject.GetAlternativeId(), out T oldSObject)) {
                        oldSObject.SalesforceError = updatedSObject.SalesforceError;
                    }
                });

            return oldSObjectByAlternativeIds;
        }
```

It will be noticed there are only 3 differences other than the method name:

- The very end of the url
- The property on `oldSObject` of type `T` which will receive a new value.
- The property on `updatedSObject`of type `TU` which will supply the old value.

Is there some way I can consolidate these into something like this (pseudocode, doesn't work):

```
        public Dictionary<string, T> UpdateProperties<T, TU>(Dictionary<string, T> oldSObjectByAlternativeIds, List<TU> updatedSObjects, string receiverField, string supplierField)
        where TU : T
        where T : AlternativeIdentifiable {
            updatedSObjects.ForEach((updatedSObject) => {
                    if (oldSObjectByAlternativeIds.TryGetValue(updatedSObject.GetAlternativeId(), out T oldSObject)) {
                        oldSObject.set(receiverField, updatedSObject.get(supplierField));
                    }
                });

            return oldSObjectByAlternativeIds;
        }
```

?

The last two parameters needn't be strings; I'd actually prefer something typesafe.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: `where TU : T` - If that's the case, why do you need `TU` at all, and if that's the case, wouldn't `typeof (updatedSObject) == T.GetType()`?

Comment: Create a private worker method that includes all the logic and includes a URL and corresponding property parameters.  At this point, the body of your two methods simple becomes a call to the worker method.  If you can't pass the property by value, you probably can pass the getters/setters in as delegates

Comment: @JoshE, Long story short, this solution is being build for a Salesforce integration with the Bulk API 2.0.  When I serialize the data as a CSV, I don't want to include some fields, but when I get feedback from Salesforce, I want to inject those values back into the appropriate instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `Action<T, TU>`, which could be: `(oldSObject, updatedSObject) => oldSObject.SalesforceError = updatedSObject.SalesforceError`:

```
public Dictionary<string, T> UpdateFailureProperties<T, TU>(Dictionary<string, T> oldSObjectByAlternativeIds, List<TU> updatedSObjects, Action<T, TU> callback)
    where TU : T
    where T : AlternativeIdentifiable
{
    updatedSObjects.Get(url, context.token)
        .FromCsv<List<TU>>()
        .ForEach((updatedSObject) =>
        {
            if (oldSObjectByAlternativeIds.TryGetValue(updatedSObject.GetAlternativeId(), out T oldSObject))
            {
                callback(oldSObject, updatedSObject);
            }
        });

    return oldSObjectByAlternativeIds;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.  Not entirely sure how I would invoke this since `updatedSObject` doesn't exist in the context of the caller (maybe the compiler doesn't care?).  Trying...

Comment: @BrianKessler Good point; your `Action` needs to accept both types. See my update.